# Import numerical value from a website to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to import a numerical value from [this website](https://dps.psx.com.pk/company/SYS) to [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QLwNsazCvUU_h54aowdhidN8gKZ3M9E4b7eu_pN8F8g/edit?usp=sharing).
I want to import LDCP (last day closing price) in cell B2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@data-name='REG']//div[div[@class='stats_label']/text()='LDCP']/div[@class='stats_value']")
```

- In this case, the URL of `https://dps.psx.com.pk/company/SYS` is put in the cell "A1".
- When you want to put the value to the cell "B2", please put `=IMPORTXML("https://dps.psx.com.pk/company/SYS","//div[@data-name='REG']//div[div[@class='stats_label']/text()='LDCP']/div[@class='stats_value']")` to the cell "B2".
- I thought that in this case, the following formula can be also used.

  ```
    =IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@data-name='REG']//div[@class='stats_value'][../div[@class='stats_label']/text()='LDCP']")
  ```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- The XPath of this sample formula is for your URL of `https://dps.psx.com.pk/company/SYS`. So, when you changed the URL, the XPath might not be able to be used. So please be careful about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@data-name='REG']"),2,4),"LDCP(\d+\.\d+)")
```

[image]

assuming that `=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@data-name='REG']"))` will give you these informations
[image]

By `index` I fetch the cell I need, then I apply a simple `regexextract` formula.

This way you can easily retrieve other information.

Comment: This formula 
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@data-name='REG']"),2,4),"LDCP(\d+\.\d+)")  when entered in cell, shows #N/A.  User Tanaike provided the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Not in my side (formula in A2). I have added a screen shot. Please give me a sample spreadsheet to investigate.

Comment: User Tanaike [https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike] provided the formula. I found the solution. However here's the link to spreadsheet in case you want to see it. [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QLwNsazCvUU_h54aowdhidN8gKZ3M9E4b7eu_pN8F8g/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: Of course it couldn't work since A1 is not an url!

Comment: No doubt that tanaike's formula works, as mine, with in A1 an url!